# How to append a component to an HTML document in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a document like

```
var target = document.getElementById('state')
```

As we append another div with `id="data"` like

```
target.appendChild(document.getElementById('data'))
```

I want to append a component `<Test />` to the `target`. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would create new element, append it to `target` and use that element in `ReactDOM.render()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not react way of doing things, in react you make components to have states or receive props. In your case to append another div is conditional, so in your react component you can maintain a state and based on that state render the `<Test/>` component

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to use a loop to render or create dynamic Elements in html like:

```
<div>
   {testsData.map(data => {
      return (<Test {...data} />);
   })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it in the normal react way.

doing as you wish is exposing your site to attacks.

here is an example how to do it [dangerously example](https://www.skptricks.com/2018/12/working-with-react-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-attribute.html)

here is why not to do it [react official dangerously](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

Comment: If this is not secured, could you suggest a secured way?

Comment: Its to long to explain I can only tell you that in react you dont have a reason to use query(getElement...)
you can use "ref" attribute in the element to ref it